# how to store and retrieve data from sqlite table in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert date,month,year and events in a table,and retrieve the event of a particular day, when the date is selected from a date picker!!

I have been searching about it, but got no convincing ideas!!

please if someone could help me out...

thanks

Comment: Keep searching. There are lots of SQLite examples out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the SQLite Database table by executing the query to create a new table according to your constraints.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+employeeTable+" 
    ("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        colName+" TEXT, "+colAge+" Integer, "+colDept+" 
    INTEGER NOT NULL ,FOREIGN KEY ("+colDept+") REFERENCES 
    "+deptTable+" ("+colDeptID+"));");
```

Use [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) to update/insert data in the table.

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
   cv.put(colDeptID, 1);
   cv.put(colDeptName, "Sales");
   db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);

   cv.put(colDeptID, 2);
   cv.put(colDeptName, "IT");
   db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
   db.close();
```

and [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) to retrieve data from the table.

```
Cursor getAllDepts()
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colDeptID+" as _id, 
    "+colDeptName+" from "+deptTable,new String [] {});

   return cur;
  }
```

**Source :** [This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) explains everything in more detail.

**Disclaimer :** This answer is only to help you understand how to work with SQLite (as you say that you haven't been able to come across any convincing ideas). You would need to write your own code to handle the logic of retrieving the events according to the date selected in the DatePicker, but I think that should not be much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good sqlite tutorial and if you read and follow the instructions it will work.
Don't forget to insert the date in the format ("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm") otherwise sqlite will not be able to sort your dates in descending or ascending order, if you would want to ask for it.

good luck

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/